# jQuery multiple selection does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a divs that get created with an id, and I add span with preset CSS properties

```
$(".main").append("<div class=largeBox id=" + counter + "</div>");
$(".largeBox").append("<span class=mainTitle></span>");
```

Then I am trying to load text into boxes, but selection could not work. Can anyone advise me why?

```
var id = "#" + counter;
$(id + " .mainTitle").text(title);
```

Comment: can you try with find `$(id).find('.mainTitle').length;` to check if there is element that exist with that class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **don't** actually need to have quotes around classnames or IDs and I purposely omitted them in my answer to show that's not the problem here. 
Your had a problem that you were actually appending all the spans to all the previous largebox divs. I added a `for` loop so you can see how it works now but the use of `$(".largeBox").eq(counter)` makes the titles append to each div separately.

Also, IDs shouldn't start with a number (if you want to support HTML4 browsers), so now their form is `lb-number` (lb for largeBox)

```js
var counter = 0;
for(counter=0;counter<5;counter++){
$(".main").append("<div class=largeBox id=lb-" + counter + "></div>");
$(".largeBox").eq(counter).append("<span class='mainTitle'></span>");
  
var id = "#lb-" + counter;
$(id + " .mainTitle").text("test");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You append is not entirely correct. You nee to add quotes around the class and id properties.

Also you miss a closing > tag of your div.

```
$(".main").append('<div class="largeBox" id="' + counter + '"></div>');
$(".largeBox").append('<span class="mainTitle"></span>');
```

Comment: you forgot to do proper string concatenation at `id=" + counter + "`

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the class and id values inside quotes. There is two types of quotes you can use: `"` and `'`.

```js
var counter = 0;

$(".main").append("<div class='largeBox' id='" + counter + "'></div>");
$(".largeBox").append("<span class='mainTitle'></span>");

var id = "#" + counter;
$(id + " .mainTitle").text("test");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">

</div>
```